# JSON Query in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, json

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (id,lat,lon)
AS VALUES
  ( 1, 34, 45 ),
  ( 1, 45, 56 ),
  ( 2, 56, 67 ),
  ( 2, 58, 64 );
```

How can I get JSON like that:

```
{"1":[[34,45],[45,56]], "2":[[56,67],[58,64]]}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with spatial, or geojson.

Comment: The spatial solution is actually much easier, but then you don't store points in a table. You store either lines or MULTIPOINTs. and you can use PostGIS's `ST_ToGeoJSON`

Comment: I have an ability to save them like Postgis geom::point, can u provide this solution also?

Comment: no, it's a totally different question that requires you store a GEOGRAPHY or GEOMETRY type on the table, install the PostGIS extension, save all your points in a totally different format, and then query the table differently. It would take 25 pages for me to go over that setup and explain what's happening. I do however **HIGHLY** suggest the PostGIS in Action book if you're looking for direction and you want to learn GIS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you do something like this,

```
SELECT id, jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_array(lat,lon)) AS j
FROM foo
GROUP BY id;
```

That aggregates the values into an JSON Array. You get

```
 id |          j           
----+----------------------
  2 | [[56, 67], [58, 64]]
  1 | [[34, 45], [45, 56]]
```

From there you need to build an JSON Object..

```
SELECT jsonb_object_agg(id,j)
FROM (
  SELECT id, jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_array(lat,lon)) AS j
  FROM foo
  GROUP BY id
) AS t;
```